# Add up parameters in for loop

Tags: bash, variables, increment

I've implemented a function which contains a while `for` loop defined as follows:

```
func()
{
...
 for i in "$@"; do
     enum="source"
     sourceID=$i
     ret_ID $FILE_NAME $sourceID $enum
     ID=$req_ID
     ((ID+=ID))
 done
 echo $ID
}
```

The function `ret_ID` parses a file which contains some variables as

```
param1=0x00000001
param2=0x00000400
param3=0x000008000
...
```

No matter how many parameters I pass, `echo $ID` returns the ID associated with the last parameter and not the sum of all of them. For instance, `func param1 param3` returns `32768` and not `32769`.

Comment: req_ID is a variable set in ret_ID function and retrieved here

Comment: `$ID` can never be an odd value. You set it's value, then double it. You are not *accumulating* anything. You only return twice the **last** value of `$req_ID`. Did you mean `((ID+=req_ID))`?

Comment: Also, relying on global ideas is a bad idea. `ret_ID` should *return* a value, not just *set* a global variable.

Comment: I am agree. I modified the line as ID=$(ret_ID $FILE_NAME $sourceID $enum) and an echo $ID displays the good value.

Comment: I solved the problem with these two lines. ID=$(ret_ID $FILE_NAME $sourceID $enum) followed by ((VAR+=ID)). Echo $VAR returned the required value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: Judging by a comment by the OP, it sounds like [glenn jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7552/glenn-jackman)'s recommendation to switch from letting `ret_ID()` *set a global variable* in order to return its result to *outputting its result to stdout* and capturing the result in a command substitution (`$(...)`) solved the problem.

<sup>Assuming that the problem wasn't the simple *logic* error Glenn points out (`((ID+=ID))` should be `((ID+=req_ID ))`: The exact cause of the original problem is not known, but since both `func()` and `ret_ID()` operate on *global* variables, it's easy to see how one function could interfere with the other, such as if `ret_ID()` accidentally also sets variable `$ID`.</sup>

Here's a rewrite of the function that shows this change, and also suggests a few other changes to make the function more robust, most notably the **use of *local* variables**:

```
func()
{
 # Declare *local* variables.
 local arg enum sourceID retID 
 # Declare the local result variable *as an integer*
 # Also, better to use variable names that at least start with a *lowercase*
 # letter to avoid conflicts with *environment* variables.
 local -i id=0 
 # ...
 for arg; do  # loop over all args; the `in "$@"` part is optional
   enum="source"
   sourceID=$arg
   # Call helper function and let it return its result via *stdout* captured
   # through a command substitution rather than by setting a global variable.
   # Note the use of double quotes to prevent problems with values with embedded spaces.
   reqID=$(ret_ID "$FILE_NAME" "$sourceID" "$enum")
   # Add the value returned to $id
   # Note that since $id was declared as an integer,
   # use of (( ... )) is optional.
   id+=$reqID
 done
 echo "$id"
}
```

Comment: Thank mklement0 for your advices, I will take them in account !!

Comment: @SnP: My pleasure. It looks like you've accepted few, if any, of the questions you've asked over time, so let me offer this standard advice: For the benefit of both answerers and future readers: If an answer _solved_ your problem, please _accept it_ by clicking the large check mark next to it; if you found it _helpful_, please _up-vote_ it by clicking the up-arrow icon.

Comment: @SnP: Thanks for accepting; it would be great if you went through your old questions and also accepted answers there, if appropriate. Aside from showing appreciation, it really helps future readers to know what answer actually solved a problem.